# Reformatting a CSV using Python and bucketing the data

Tags: python, csv

I know that there must be dozens of "correct" ways to do this, but I would like to get your opinion on what is the best practice / smartest way of doing the following.

I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
Date,Num,name,Aging,Open Balance
07/16/2012,12-001270,8,1,"-8,934.75"
07/18/2012,12-2429,24,34,2.00
07/18/2012,12-2428,24,58,85.00
07/18/2012,12-2420,8,58,"4,381.90"
```

And I need it to look more like this format:

```
name,num,date,0-30,31-60,61-90,91+,total
8,12-001270,7/16/2012,"-8,934.75",0,0,0,"-8,934.75"
8,12-2420,07/18/2012,0,"4,381.90",0,0,"4,381.90"
24,12-2428,07/18/2012,0,2,85,87
```

The question is: is there a plug and play solution in python that can bucket data this way ?

I would take the `Aging` column data and break up into different ranges and reformat data as shown.

What would be the most effecient way to do this?

Comment: How are the values of the desired output to be computed from the input?`Where does `Name`, `Total`,  and the other columns come from?

Comment: @Tichodroma thank you i forgot to label NAME column. also the total is just the total of the open balance for those specific aging brackets

Comment: Have you looked into Python's [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)?

Comment: @TimPietzcker its a plain text file, but i say csv because the fields are separated by commas

Comment: @TimPietzcker under the fields labeled 0-30/31-60/61 etc... there would be those $ amounts that correspond to the ranges

Comment: @TimPietzcker thanks so much for your feedback. ive elucidated.

Comment: @Tichodroma i've updated! please let me know if anything else needs clarification

Comment: I'm puzzled about the last line in your new csv file. Why are there two of the age columns filled with data ("2" doesn't seem to belong there since in the original, it has a different "num"), and the total doesn't match, either.

Comment: there's only one aging column. you must be puzzled by number before the aging? that number is in the NAME column

Comment: I mean the age brackets. Specifically, why is there a `2` in the fifth column of `24,12-2428,07/18/2012,0,2,85,0,2.00`? Why isn't the total `87`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker that was a silly mistake. thanks to you, i clarified my post

Comment: OK, thanks. Still unclear to me: What happened to `12-2429`?

Comment: thank you. nothing happened to it. i just didnt include it in the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of bits to get you started...

**Reading the file and accessing values**

```
with open('somefile.csv') as fin:
    csvin = csv.DictReader(fin)
    for row in csvin:
        print 'Person {name} had a balance of {Open Balance}'.format(**row)
```

**Formatting your amount so it's usable**

```
import re

s = "-8,934.75"
try:
    amount = float(re.sub('[^-.0-9]', '', s))
except ValueError as e:
    pass # wasn't valid for some reason? do something sensible
```

**'Bucketing' data**

```
from bisect import bisect

def age_band(age, upto=[30, 60, 90], desc=['0-30', '31-60', '61-90', '91+']):
    if not age >= 0:
        return '*invalid*'
    return desc[bisect(upto, age)]

for age in [31, 99, 65, 12, -1]:
    print age, age_band(age)
```